# styles are not rendering via innerHTML

Tags: angular, innerhtml

I am using angular 13.3.7.

I create my own custom build(https://ckeditor.com/ckeditor-5/online-builder/), get the ckeditor.js and add it on my angular project.
My problem is that all the style from fontColor plugins or Alignment plugins works only on the editor, not in the output.

the console.log prints all the data with styles:

But on my template where I print the data:

`div [innerHtml]="testData">`

How I can keep all the styles?

Using bypassSecurityTrustHtml resolved the issue, but this will bypass the sanitization. Without the sanitization, I can't use fontColor plugin at all.

Comment: Your question seems to be missing some detail. In order to help you we need a [Minimal Reproducible Example](//stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) directly in your question.  Please [edit your question](//stackoverflow.com/posts/76869695/edit) and add some more code to your question.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.